# Solving systems of equations with 3 unknowns

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I have a question about finding the unknown values of systems of equations. For example, if I had the following 6 equations:

```
                    1) A + B + C = 10    4) A + D + G = 100
                    2) D + E + F = 20    5) B + E + H = 200
                    3) G + H + I = 30    6) C + F + I = 300
```

Is it possible to find the values of each given letter (A to I)? It seems that there are endless possibilities if no constraints are placed (*e.g. A>=0, A is a whole number, etc.*); this would likely require a programming software to compute the unknown values as each letter can take several different values in this instance.

Is there any way to solve such a type of question, or has anyone had any experience with such question?

Many thanks,

Comment: If you don't know linear algebra, you can solve for $A$ in the first equation and substitute that formula throughout the remaining equations (resulting in $5$ equations).  Keep doing that with the remaining variables until you either reach a contradiction or get the answer.

Answer (score 2):

not consistent. the first three say the sum of all nine letters is 60. The second three say the sum is 600

note that the 3 by 3 matrix on the right is the transpose of that on the left. The thing I said above is $V^T A V = 60,$ where $V$ is the column vector with all entries $1.$ But then we get $V^T A^T V = 600.$ And, the transpose of a 1 by one matrix (a number) is itself.